# Get system information UWP

Tags: c++, qt, uwp

I want to develop the `Universal Windows Application` which will display the system information such as `RAM` capacity, `GPU` information, `Drives` and so on. I used the `WMI` for `Win32 (Desktop)` app. From the official `UWP` documentation I can't use the `WMI`. So how to get such information? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking at WinRT or Win32 docs or the UWP samples to see which APIs are available?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT

I haven't check the UWP samples. Thank you.

Comment: maybe you'll find something helpful here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile

Comment: @JetChopper

Ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which will display the system information such as RAM capacity, GPU information, Drives and so on.

For RAM, UWP can only access to information on current app's memory usage by using the [`MemoryManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.memorymanager) Class.

For GPU information, currently there is no API can access GPU directly in UWP app. You may need to create a [UWP app with DirectX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/directx-getting-started) and access the information by DirectX. You may find some relative samples [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples).

For access any one local drive, you need to use [`FileOpenPicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker) since UWP app need [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) . And you can find the sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FilePicker).

As you can already access the information you want in a Win32 app, you could also try to use [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) to convert the Win32 desktop app to UWP.