# Choose project template for dll that uses WMI

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, inno-setup, libraries

*This is not a duplicate of [Getting System Info in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47984097/get-system-information-uwp) although an attempt to use a UWP library was mentioned. That failed and was not my real mission. The real mission is finding a library template that can be used for a number of reasons. And for that, I think I'm close.*

**== UPDATE==**

Object is to build a dll that will be consumed by Inno Setup. Other responsibilities are accessing WMI functions, OLEDB, the registry, displaying user dialogues and some significant computation. The thought being that variable data would persist during the lifetime of the installation process as a number of calls would be made to the library for different services.

The library makes calls to WMI methods to gather system information, accesses an Access database to add tables, data and make other updates, presents Windows forms for user input and calculate licensing tokens.

Compatibility issues referencing different library types, like UWP with.NET library, forced a decision to use a WinForms library. At least the WinForms library could reference other .NET class libraries containing code for WMI calls, working with OLEDB etc.

There was a period of trying to develop a library with WinForms that could also expose methods to unmanaged code. Included in that period was discovering how to manage methods that called asynchronous methods and be called from Inno.

---

**== UPDATE==**

For .NET 5+ there is a package that will "fix" the .il file so that manual edits needed to  expose the library are unnecessary. So that question is answered except that it is limited to x86, which is okay. However, Inno Setup making a call to a function that is asynchronous is either unsupported or I am too weary of searching for a working solution. So, the exposed functions revert to standard calls and the calls to asynchronous methods from them use and invoke format. Beyond that, a WinForms library is possible and can be called from Framework, not the other way around.

I think when I'm done with this project I will turn it into an article.